# In a CSV, how do I loop through column names and get their position in the header row?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```
ID,Name,Age
1,John,99
```

I've `require`d `csv` in my Ruby script.

But using `CSV`, how do I loop thru the header row? How do I find the position number for `ID`,`Name` and `Age`?

Comment: can you please be a bit more clear about what you mean by `postition`

Comment: @Alfie I want my script to show that ID is at 0, Name at 1, Age at 2. Like an array.

Comment: `row[0]`, `row[1]`, `row[2]`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After copying your data to a file `x.csv`, I executed the following in irb:

```
2.3.0 :009 > require 'csv'
 => false
2.3.0 :010 > csv = CSV.read 'x.csv'
 => [["ID", "Name", "Age"], ["1", "John", "99"]]
2.3.0 :010 > csv = CSV.read 'x.csv'
 => [["ID", "Name", "Age"], ["1", "John", "99"]]
2.3.0 :011 > header_line = csv[0]
 => ["ID", "Name", "Age"]
2.3.0 :012 > header_line[0]
 => "ID"
2.3.0 :013 > header_line[1]
 => "Name"
2.3.0 :014 > header_line[2]
 => "Age"
```

...so this is one way you can do it; use `read` to get an array of arrays, and assume the first is an array of column headings.

In the real world you probably won't want to read the entire file into memory at once and would use `CSV.foreach`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

data = []
CSV.foreach('x.csv') do |values_in_row|
  if @column_names  # column names already read; this must be a data line
    data << values_in_row  # just an example
    # do something with values_in_row
  else
    @column_names = values_in_row
  end
end

puts "Column names are: #{@column_names.join(', ')}"
puts "Data lines are:"
puts data
```